# How many solutions for this equation using combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, factorial

In combinatoric, with the equation $$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+\dots +x_n=k,\quad x_i \geq 0,$$ we know, that the number of solutions is: 
$$ \left({n\choose k}\right)={n+k-1 \choose n-1}=\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!\cdot k!} $$

Is there a way in combinatoric to find the numbers of solution for an equations like
$$a_1\cdot x_1+a_2\cdot x_2+a_3\cdot x_3 + \dots + a_n\cdot x_n=k, \quad x_i \geq 0,$$ 
where we know the values of $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n$?

Comment: I believe that, unfortunately, no. It mostly reduced to tedious counting. There are some special cases which are slightly easier, like if $ a_1 \mid a_2 \mid a_3 \ldots$

Answer (score 2):

The number of solutions is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the generating function

$$
\prod_{i=1}^n\frac1{1-x^{a_i}}\;.
$$

Comment: Although that's really just a rephrasing of the problem, unless it helps you solve it.

Comment: I think it does help you solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree with the first answer. Here I'm just going to explain why it is corect.

If we had $x_1 +x_2 +x_3+ \cdots +x_n =k$, then the number of integer solutions to this equation, where $x_i \ge 0$,is equal to the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of 
$$\underbrace{(1+x+x^2+ \cdots)\ldots(1+x+x^2+\cdots)}_{\text{n times}},$$

i.e., $[x^k] (1+x+x^2+ \cdots )^n$. This method works because from each one of the $n$ brackets in the product, the exponents of $x$ are added to get certain numbers and the coefficient of $x^k$ would be equal to the number of ways we can get $k$ by adding $n$ non-negative integers.

Now, for $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 +a_3x_3 + \cdots + a_nx_n=k$,
the number of integer solutions would be the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $$(1+x^{a_1}+x^{2a_1}+\ldots)(1+x^{a_2}+x^{2a_2}+\ldots)\cdots (1+x^{a_n}+x^{2a_n}+\ldots)$$
because here the numbers that you add up have to be integer multiples of $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$.

That simplifies to $$[x^k] \left(\frac{1}{1-x^{a_1}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-x^{a_2}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-x^{a_3}}\right) \cdots \left(\frac{1}{1-x^{a_n}}\right)$$

$$=[x^k] \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1- x^{a_i}}$$

Comment: Right. And then what do you do? Is there any way to calculate the coefficient of $x^k$ in that product that's any simpler than just counting the solutions directly?

Comment: Okay that is correct. I agree. There is no simple way to find the coefficient I suppose.

Comment: Counting the solutions manually is easier than using this formula.